# jQuery Full Calendar: How to update calendar after completed ajax call?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

```
eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, revertAction) {
    $.post("/calendar/",{id: event.id } , 
        function(result) {
            if (result == "succeed"){
                alert('succeed');
            }
            else{
                alert("Server error, Please try again");
            }
         },"json");
}
```

So in this method, I have an ajax call. I want the calendar to only be updated when success is returned from the server, otherwise it does nothing. How is this kind of code written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/rerenderEvents/

```
.fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' )
```

Comment: But we need to call this event after we send new events json-array. My problem is how can we push the newly created event's json into the current array ? :/

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("/calendar/", {id: event.id }, 
    function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        // use data if textStatus == 200
    },
    "json"
);
```

?? see [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) documentation

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know which code controls the calendar updating event.